# http request using sockets on c++

Tags: c++, http, sockets, request

I'm trying to do an HTTP request using sockets on Linux, and my function works now, but only with simple domains as `www.google.com` or `webpage.000webhostapp.com`. When I try to add a path and query like `webpage.000webhostapp.com/folder/file.php?parameter=value`, it starts failing.

This is my code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
 int socket_desc;
 struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
 struct hostent *server;
 char buffer[4096];

 std::string url = "www.exampleweb.com/folder/file.php";

 socket_desc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
 if(socket_desc < 0){
  std::cout<<"failed to create socket"<<std::endl;
 }

 server = gethostbyname(url.c_str());
 if(server==NULL){std::cout<<"could Not resolve hostname :("<<std::endl;}
 bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
 serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
 serv_addr.sin_port = htons(80);
 bcopy((char *)server->h_addr,
         (char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,
         server->h_length);

 if(connect(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0){
   std::cout<<"connection failed :("<<std::endl;
 }
 std::string request = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: " + url + "\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n";

 if(send(socket_desc, request.c_str(), strlen(request.c_str())+1, 0) < 0){
  std::cout<<"failed to send request..."<<std::endl;
 }
 int n;
 std::string raw_site;
 while((n = recv(socket_desc, buffer, sizeof(buffer)+1, 0)) > 0){
  int i = 0;
        while (buffer[i] >= 32 || buffer[i] == '\n' || buffer[i] == '\r'){

            raw_site+=buffer[i];
            i += 1;
        }
 }

 std::cout<<raw_site<<std::endl;
 return 0;
}
```

Using `www.google.com`, it works perfectly for the request.

Using `www.example.com/folder/file.php?parameter=value&parameter2=value2`, it fails and returns `"could not resolve hostname"`.

Any idea on how to fix it?

I'm not using curl and can't use it for this project.

Comment: You should parse the url for getting its parts. Or use libcurl.

Comment: Also learn http protocol more carefully. `GET / HTTP/1.1` is not valid for the url "www.exampleweb.com/folder/file.php".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`gethostbyname()` (which BTW is deprecated, you should be using `getaddrinfo()` instead) does not work with URLs, only with host names.

Given a URL like `http://www.exampleweb.com/folder/file.php?parameter=value&parameter2=value2`, you need to first break it up into its constituent pieces (read [RFC 3986](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986)), eg:

- the scheme `http`
- the host name `www.exampleweb.com`
- the resource path `/folder/file.php`
- the query `?parameter=value&parameter2=value2`

You can then resolve the IP address for the host, connect to that IP address on port 80 (the default port for HTTP) since the URL doesn't specify a different port, and finally send a `GET` request for the resource and query.

Also, note that the `Host` header in the `GET` request must specify *only* the host name (and port, if different than the default), not the whole URL. And also that HTTP requests are not null-terminated strings, so do not send the null terminator. Read [RFC 2616](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2616).

Try this instead:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int socket_desc;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    struct hostent *server;
    char buffer[4096];

    std::string host = "www.exampleweb.com";
    std::string port = "80";
    std::string resource = "/folder/file.php";
    std::string query = "?parameter=value&parameter2=value2";

    socket_desc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (socket_desc < 0){
        std::cout << "failed to create socket" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    server = gethostbyname(host.c_str());
    if (server == NULL){
        std::cout << "could Not resolve hostname :(" << std::endl;
        close(socket_desc);
        return 0;
    }

    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(std::stoi(port));
    bcopy((char *)server->h_addr, (char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr, server->h_length);

    if (connect(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0){
        std::cout << "connection failed :(" << std::endl;
        close(socket_desc);
        return 0;
    }

    std::string request = "GET " + resource + query + " HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: " + host + "\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n";

    if (send(socket_desc, request.c_str(), request.size(), 0) < 0){
        std::cout << "failed to send request..." << std::endl;
        close(socket_desc);
        return 0;
    }

    int n;
    std::string raw_site;
    while ((n = recv(socket_desc, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0)) > 0){
        raw_site.append(buffer, n);
    }

    close(socket_desc);

    std::cout << raw_site << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```